# Use SKProduct in normal class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I have `StoreKit` set up in my project and I can get product information from the app store fine, that's all working.

What I'm now trying to do is add an `SKProduct` as an instance variable in a class of mine, as below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface VideoCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *title;
    IBOutlet UILabel *description;
    SKProduct *product;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (retain) IBOutlet UILabel *description;
@property (retain) SKProduct *product;
```

It works fine with just the `IBOutlet` variables but the `SKProduct` lines have errors, as follows:

```
Unknown type name 'SKProduct'
```

I'm confused because the class name auto-completes but doesn't actually compile...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any import for StoreKit in this snippet of code, is it missing?

Comment: It's generally just available to all classes in the project.. is that normal?

Comment: This is normal behavior. Unless you did the #import already in your "xx-Prefix.pch" prefix header file, in which case the class would be accessible from any file in your project. Otherwise, using the default behavior you would have to import it yourself into each file that uses that class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the import:

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
```